# Two ".htaccess" Files Located in Different Directories?

Tags: url-rewriting, htaccess, options

I found two ".htaccess" files, one is located in '/httpdocs/.htaccess', another one is located in '/httpdocs/wordpress/.htaccess', the content is different, is it normal?

The Wordpress was installed on '/wordpress/' dir, then never changed, but when users go to my site, the URL shows "http://www.mydomain.com", no 'wordpress' shown on the URL.

Also, from Settings > General:

WordPress Address (URL): http://www.mydomain.com/wordpress

Site Address (URL): http://www.mydomain.com

Comment: Hi you already asked this question as a comment on your other question today about .htaccess.  You just need to delete one or just leave them there

Comment: But the contents of two files is not the same..

Answer (score 3):

In general, Apache will use the most specific .htaccess to the resource being requested.  This means that, for accessing files in `/httpdocs/wordpress/`, `/httpdocs/wordpress/.htaccess` will be used.  Access to `/httpdocs/foo/` will use `/httpdocs/foo/.htaccess` and, if that doesn't exist, it will use `/httpdocs/.htaccess`.

If your document root is pointing to `/httpdocs/wordpress/`, then users will see `http://www.example.com` as your WordPress directory.  Also, if your `/httpdocs/.htaccess` includes rewriting to hide the `wordpress` in your folder name, the same will happen.

Comment: This is the content from "wordpress/.htaccess", only used by BetterWPSecurity: 

    # BEGIN Better WP Security
    # Begin HackRepair.com Blacklist
    RewriteEngine on
    #Block comment spammers, bad bots and some proxies
    RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} 12.226.240.248 [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} 24.111.102.26 [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} 24.117.121.113 [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} 65.30.216.140 [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} 67.87.64.23 [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} 68.12.149.198 [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} 69.139.167.203 [OR]
    ...

Comment: This is the content from "/.htaccess": 

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Comment: It seems some plugins are using "wordpress/.htaccess", but "/.htaccess" is also working, do you think it is safe to keep working like that?  Thanks.

Comment: As lacqui mentioned in his answer, Apache will get what ever it needs from all .htaccesses that you create but those that are more specific will overrule those closer to the root directory. This means you can have your rules split over multiple files. Or even shorter: Yes its ok to keep it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you have WordPress installed in a subdirectory. There is an in-depth explanation about that in the codex:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory

Step 7 mentions that the .htaccess file should be *copied* and not moved from the subdirectory to the root.
So yes, having two .htaccess files is normal when you have set up your WordPress installation in a subdirectory.

Comment: But the contents is not the same, please check the contents in another comments on this page. Thanks.